# How to bind transition end event to multiple elements without having multiple executions of the function?

Tags: jquery, css, event-handling

I have a list which contains images and I move them with a css transition.

Because those images are big, I have to use css transition on the list elements to avoid a flicker on Safari.

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="moveLeft>...</li>
    <li class="moveLeft">...</li>
    <li class="moveLeft>...</li>
    <li class="moveLeft>...</li>
    <li class="moveLeft>...</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that the function binded to the transition end is executed 5 times (the amount of elements) if I use bind on the ul element :

```
$("container").bind("webkitTransitionEnd", function() {
    doSomething()
});
```

I tried to bind the event handler on the second children of the list, but because **list elements are updated (elements deleted, added)**, the event handler will stop when the second element will be replaced.

```
$("container").children().eq(2).bind("webkitTransitionEnd", function() {
    doSomething()
});
```

I think the solution is to bind the event handler to the parent, but how could I do to execute the function one time instead of five each time the event is fired ?

Answer (score 0):

To bind only to the parent li(in your case):
you can use `nth-child()`

Eg:

```
$("#container li:nth-child(1)").bind("webkitTransitionEnd", function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
function doSomething() {
  //do something

}
```

Comment: When the list is updated (first element removed, new element added at the last position or last element removed, new element added at the first position), the event listener doesn't work anymore if the element on which the event was bound is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.live()` instead of `.bind()` or, even better, the new `.on()`.
The .on() method replaces all previous event handler attachement : http://api.jquery.com/on/

But, in your case, it may be more efficient (performance-wise) to use only one transition (a translate), on the `<ul>`, to move together all the `<li>` it contains.

Comment: I know it's more efficient to use the transition on the container, but as its size is larger than the window size and there's a bug on Safari which causes a flicker if the element using a css transition is bigger than the window size.